# How can I label things in the Dock?

Tags: software-recommendation, xcode, dock, git

I have two XCode projects I open regularly, so I added them to the Dock. Unfortunately, they're not labeled. Hovering doesn't help, since it shows the same name. In fact, they're two different Git workspaces with the same project, so I want to label the icon with the name of folder it's in.

How do I do that?

I'm open to third-party apps.

I don't want to edit anything in the folder, since that will show up as an edit in Git.

[image]

Comment: Is a custom icon for one or both an acceptable “label”? I use color sometimes for special icons and a quick edit of the stock icon is low effort.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work, since I have a dozen Git workspaces.

Comment: That won't do because changing dozen icons is too much work?

Comment: Yes, and I regularly keep creating new workspaces. Besides, as I edited the question to say, I don't want to edit anything in the folder, since that will show up as an edit in Git.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's a bit of a kludge but it should work:

- Open `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/xcode-project_Icon.icns` in an editor like Preview or GIMP.
- Select whichever resolution you want to modify.
- Add whatever text you want, e.g. the project workspace name.

  - Side note: This may ask you to duplicate the file before editing it. Don't worry about this.
- *** Do not save this! *** (You probably won't be able to anyway.)
- Press File > Save As... while holding Option, or press ⇧⌥⌘S, and save it as a PNG somewhere, if you want to keep it around. (I would recommend this, but you certainly don't have to.)

  - If you're using a third-party image editor like GIMP, you may not have to use the Option key.

---

- Open the PNG you just saved. (Or if you chose not to save it, ignore this step.)
- Select All (⌘A), and copy it (⌘C).
- Go to the project you want to change the icon of.
- Press File > Get Info (⌘I).
- Click on the icon in the *top left* of the info window, and paste (⌘V).

---

The second part of this also works for *any* icon you might have laying around! You can change  the icons of anything, including folders and even apps, this way. (But if you're changing an app icon, be aware that some apps change their own icon while they're running. It'll change back when the app quits. For example, Firefox does this when downloading a file.)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to edit anything in the folder, since that will show up as an edit in Git.

Comment: @VaddadiKartick Is that an assumption or did you test it? I just tested it and it didn't show up at all in my test git. Changed the icon a few times too. This is probably the only way to do it if you want to keep it in the dock like that. I pretty much have only 3 alternatives to changing the icon and they are all just as cumbersome if not more..

Comment: Yes, that will show up in git—unless you add `Icon*` to your .gitignore file. (It's literally named `Icon\r`, where `\r` is a literal carriage return, but I haven't figured out how to put that in .gitignore.)

Comment: Whoops, should have said `Icon?` instead. That way you can still have files named "Icon-256.png" or whatever.

Comment: I may have to try again, because I sure didn't add anything to gitignore...

Comment: What do you mean? Did you accidentally commit the icon?

Comment: Tested it again and I realized what is going on there. Apparently changing icon of a file doesn't show up in git, but changing an icon of a folder does. Adding `/Icon` to .gitignore will stop tracking folder icon changes for the root folder only. Adding `Icon` to .gitignore will stop tracking changes to all files with the exact name: 'Icon'.

Comment: Nice. Out of curiosity, did you need to do anything for the literal carriage return in the name? (Also, I did it that way to prevent tracking subfolder icons. I figured it'd be unlikely to have something named `Icon_` with `_` being exactly one additional character.)